# How to return a function from react child component and use it in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import React from 'react';
I am returning this only function from a react component and using in parent component.I have a concern is it bad idea to do this or will it create any performance issue.

```
    const MyComponent = () => {
      const myFunction = () => {
        console.log('Hello, I am a function!');
      };
    
      return myFunction;
    };
    
    export default MyComponent;


//Using

import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const App = () => {
  const returnedFunction = MyComponent();

  // Call the returned function
  returnedFunction();

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Other JSX */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: It's not clear what the actual intended use is, but in a general sense, returning functions or function generators etc. is common. Here `returnedFunction` will be redefined on render; this may or may not be intended behavior.

Comment: @DaveNewton... My concern is I don't have return any jsx I have to return only function.... actually this I have added a sample but I my real project this function uses lot of react stuff which I can't use in normal js file

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is. A function doesn't need to return JSX, functions can return anything. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here--in other words, why not export `myFunction` directory? Why call the function to create the function?